# why nestjs socket.io extraHeaders value undefined?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat, nestjs

I'm sorry I can't speak English.

I've been trying to solve this problem for 6 hours already.

I'm currently implementing the chat room function, and I'm going to get the header value from the client for it.

However, the value of extraHeaders for socket.io is not properly received. Can you tell me the reason why?

front-end code:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
...

        var socket = io('http://localhost:3001/chatting', {
            origins: '*:*',
            transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket'],
            transportOptions: {
                polling: {
                    extraHeaders: {
                        Authorization:
                            'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6IndhdGVyZmxhbWUxQG5hdmVyLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTYyMDM5OTMxNywiZXhwIjoxNjIwNDAyOTE3fQ.W6Ubg53GcXud8IX_NEKnehgGjNmilwN8K3ZosG-7CSY'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Back-end code (handleConnection):

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, but I remember what I was finally able to do was to set the authorization header inside the handshake query. So from the backend, I could see it using `client.handshake.query.token`

Comment: thank you Eranga Heshan! I solved the problem above. Instead of putting it in the header, I created one authentication emit to authenticate jwt token!

Comment: @momo Hi, so don't you use client.handshake.headers.authorization to get token?

Comment: @Sangbeom Han
To be precise, we created chat authentication by referring to the following blog post.